# Android okhttp library

Tags: java, android, okhttp, android-networking, androidhttpclient

To use OkHttp in a Gradle build, I need to add the following dependency to the Gradle build.

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
```

Does that mean I am using okhttp-urlconnection module which  implements the familiar `java.net.HttpURLConnection` API OR the `okhttp-apache` module which implements the Apache HttpClient API?

Comment: okhttp is the http library implemented by Square. https://github.com/square

Comment: Use `Response/Request` API. The others will be deprecated soon. Read this:  https://publicobject.com/2015/12/15/okurlfactory-is-going-away/

Answer (score 2):

Have you copied Lines? :) :)

Documentations Says:

> You can try out OkHttp without rewriting your network code. The
>   `okhttp-urlconnection` module implements the familiar
>   `java.net.HttpURLConnection` API and the `okhttp-apache` module implements
>   the **Apache HttpClient API**.
>
> OkHttp supports Android 2.3 and above. For Java, the minimum
>   requirement is 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

It means you can use this library classes. I have used this library with retrofit.

```
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(ContextConstants.REPORT_SUBMIT_PATH)
            .setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient))
            .build();
```